# Is it possible to give an attribute a variable text?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, attributes

I have an attribute with an optional error text like so:

```
[DoubleRangeCheck(2.0, 10.0, ErrorMessage="Text shown on error")]
```

Now I want to localise the error message, so I tried

```
[DoubleRangeCheck(2.0, 10.0, ErrorMessage=Properties.Resources.MsgLocalisedError)]
```

But I get a compiler error stating that the attribute must be constant.

```
error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

So is this just not possible, or am I missing something?

How can I localise a text parameter to an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes, as the compiler states, can only be expressed in terms of constant values - they are *essentially* serialized and stored in the metadata. However, it is often possible to localize them a bit by sub-classing them, and having the subclass override some virtual method exposed for that very purpose. For example, with `[Category("Foo")]`, you can do things like:

```
class LocalizedCategoryAttribute : CategoryAttribute {
    public LocalizedCategoryAttribute(string category) : base(category) { }
    protected override string GetLocalizedString(string value)
    {
        // your code here! (treat "value" as the key)
        return base.GetLocalizedString(value);
    }
}
```

and then decorate with `[LocalizedCategory("Foo")]`. How well this works depends on both the specific attribute and the code that consumes them.

Comment: I think this is the right track. But how would I do this in a custom attribute (I have no base.GetLocalizedString)? As my attribute is in a different assembly I don't know how to get the correct ResourceManager in order to find the string.

Comment: @MTR like I say: it all comes down to whether or not `[DoubleRangeCheck(...)]` and/or the code that *checks for* that attribute have been designed with localization in mind.